# How to use POST method in laravel and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

When I use a POST method with the following ajax request, it throws a "Method not allowed" error. If I use the form POST without using ajax, it goes to the proper method.

In Router.php:

```
 $this->post('TestPost','DashboardController@TestPostMethod');
```

In View, the ajax request is:

```
$.ajax(
{           
type: "POST",
url: 'TestPost',
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
success: function (data) {  
alert('hid post');       

SetHotandWorstData(data,'hotquantity');

},

error: function (msg) {
alert('error');
alert(msg.responseText);
}
});
```

In Controller:

```
function TestPostMethod(Request $request)
{
    $hotworstsalesdata = DB::table('100_INVOICEDETAIL')              
    ->select( '100_INVOICEDETAIL.ITEMCODE','100_INVOICEDETAIL.ITEMNAME',
DB::raw('SUM("100_INVOICEDETAIL"."QTY") as 
salesqty'), DB::raw('SUM("100_INVOICEDETAIL"."AMT") as salesamt'))
    ->groupBy('100_INVOICEDETAIL.ITEMCODE','100_INVOICEDETAIL.ITEMNAME')
    ->orderBy('salesqty')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
    return Datatables::of($hotworstsalesdata)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: Maybe Laravel is confused why you are posting a string of json, when you could just post a normal post array by leaving off the quotes and removing the json content type? I know Laravel has a lot of magic, which is one of the things you get when you decide to use it. Try what I said and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

you should pass "_token" in  POST data. Laravel use token for cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. use following code in your AJAX request

```
data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"  }
```

Updated answer:

I have re-create same scenario on my system with laravel 5.4 and it's working for me.

my route (web.php) code is:

```
Route::post('/test_post', 'DashboardController@getData');
```

Javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ url('/') }}/test_post',
        data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"  },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

        error: function (msg) {

            console.log(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

DashboardController file is:

```
public function getData(Request $request) {
    print_r($request);      
}
```

Comment: I changed like this => data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},but still throwing error

Comment: try this:  data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"  } and let me know if not works

Comment: I tried like this=> type: "POST",
        url: 'TestPost',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: I have re-create same scenario on my system with laravel 5.4 and it's working for me. Please check my code above:

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got error with `DELETE` method ! I fixed by setting `csrf token` in html header and get in ajax . Hope this can solve your problem ..

```
<html>
<header>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

In ajax,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```